# F# - writing an (GA) evaluation function in F#

Tags: f#

**Background**:
I am currently working on a genetic algorithm (GA) in F#.
*(I come from a strong C# background and have only been using F# for a day now)*

**Problem:**
I have an error evaluation function to determine how valid a proposed solution is.
Lets assume a simplified error algorithm:

```
Calculate how may digits in the sequence are larger than their successor
```

Let's use `[1;6;3;6;8;9;5;]` as an example set.

so the answer would be `2` since `6>3` and `9>5`.

**My attempt so far:**
It's a failed attempt but I hope it can serve as a starting point to help me:

```
let proposedSolution = [1;6;3;6;8;9;5;]

for y in [0..proposedSolution.Length-2] do 
    printf "%d = (%d,%d) " y proposedSolution.[y] proposedSolution.[y+1] 
    if ( proposedSolution.[y] > proposedSolution.[y+1]) then printfn "!" else printfn "*"
```

with result:

```
val proposedSolution : int list = [1; 6; 3; 6; 8; 9; 5]

> 
0 = (1,6) *
1 = (6,3) !
2 = (3,6) *
3 = (6,8) *
4 = (8,9) *
5 = (9,5) !
```

So somehow I need to map the `*` and `!` to 1 and 0 and sum them but it's probably not possible with my code above.

**Question:**
How could I write this in a proper way using F#?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pattern match on the list to count this up like this:

```
let rec mismatchs xs =
    match xs with
    | [] | [_]  -> 0
    | (a::b::t) -> (if a > b then 1 else 0) + mismatchs (b::t)
```

a slight problem with that is, that the function is not tail-recursive so you get a problem with larger lists. The usual way to make it tail-recursive is using an accumulator:

```
let mismatchs xs =
    let rec mismatchs' xs acc =
        match xs with
        | [] | [_]  -> acc
        | (a::b::t) -> mismatchs (b::t) (if a > b then acc+1 else acc)
    mismatchs' xs 0
```

and of course you can also yous a `fold`:

```
let mismatchs xs =
    List.fold 
        (fun (last,acc) x -> 
            if last > x 
            then (x,acc+1) 
            else (x,acc)) 
        (0,0) xs
    |> snd
```

here the state just remembers the last seen value as well as the accumulated value of mistakes.

if you want you can even divide the problem: first mark all **problem**-places with a `1` (the other as `0`):

```
let markProblems xs =
    xs
    |> Seq.scan 
        (fun (last, _) x -> 
            if last > x 
            then (x, 1) 
            else (x, 0)) 
        (0,0)
    |> Seq.map snd
```

and then `sum` them up:

```
let mismatchs xs = 
    markProblems xs
    |> Seq.sum
```

**remark** these two above assumes, that you have positive integers as input - if not you should make the first `0` in `(0,0)` (the initial state) smaller than ever other possible value - for example `(System.Int32.MinValue, 0)`

in each case the answer will be:

```
let proposedSolution = [1;6;3;6;8;9;5;]
let answer = mismatchs proposedSolution // = 2
```

Comment: Thanks Carsten! This is the 3rd in a row that you answer all my F# questions. I'm thinking of hiring you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working on integer pairs it is easier to use `List.pairwise`. Your input data is then converted to a list of integer tuples:

```
proposedSolution 
    |> List.pairwise
val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 6); (6, 3); (3, 6); (6, 8); (8, 9); (9, 5)]
```

Once you have the list of tuples you can calculate your result in different ways. For example using `countBy`:

```
proposedSolution
    |> List.pairwise
    |> List.countBy (fun (a,b) -> a > b)
val it : (bool * int) list = [(false, 4); (true, 2)]
```

Or `fold` to get all the matching pairs:

```
proposedSolution
    |> List.pairwise
    |> List.fold (fun l (a,b) -> if (a>b) then (a,b)::l else l) []
val it : (int * int) list = [(9, 5); (6, 3)]
```

If you are working on large data sets, then you should use Seq instead of lists. For example:

```
let rnd = new System.Random(1234) // use fixed seed to generate same data set
#time
Seq.init 1000000 (fun _ -> rnd.Next(10))
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.countBy (fun (a, b) -> a > b)
    |> Seq.toList   // force evalutation of sequence
val it : (bool * int) list = [(false, 550219); (true, 449780)]
Real: 00:00:00.462, CPU: 00:00:00.453, GC gen0: 38, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using windowed. It returns the culprit values and then you can easily sum them for the answer.

```
let values = [1;6;3;6;8;9;5]

let largerInSeq s =
  s
  |> Seq.windowed 2
  |> Seq.fold (fun acc t -> if t.[1] < t.[0] then t::acc else acc) []

values |> largerInSeq |> printfn "%A"
values |> largerInSeq |> Seq.length

[[|9; 5|]; [|6; 3|]]
val it : int = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution in the end:

```
let answer = 
    [0..proposedSolution.Length-2]
        |> List.map (fun x -> if proposedSolution.[x] > proposedSolution.[x+1] then 1 else 0)  
        |> List.sum
```

Is this fine or can this be improved?

Comment: the `proposedSolution.[x]` part can be really slow for lists, and it's not really idiomatic FP (which does not say much) - in case you want to use this I would make `proposedSolution` into an array (the indexing should be much faster) - the rest is fine